# Nginx, OpenSSL with Cloudflare full SSL - handshake fail 525

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, cloudflare

I'm getting Handshake fail 525 when trying to use Full SSL option with Cloudflare. Since this is my first time trying to implement some sort of SSL certificate I don't know what could be wrong here.

My SSL cert is generated this way:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt
```

My nginx default config looks like this:

```
server {
   listen 443;
   listen [::]:443;

   root /var/www/site-laravel/public;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;

   server_name site.ee;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select full SSL in CloudFlare, but no "Full (Strict)". Strict mode requires a validated SSL certificate and does not work with a self-signed one.

Comment: Hey. I got this issue sorted out but thanks anyway. It had to do something with my nginx configuration. I was on Full which wasn't Strict :)

Comment: What did you change in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue recently. I'm not entirely sure why this occurs either, but make sure your `default_server` has an SSL certificate set.

Answer (score 0):

`ssl` should be added.

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   listen [::]:443 ssl;

   root /var/www/site-laravel/public;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;

   server_name site.ee;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```